# Empty list boolean value

Tags: python, list, boolean

This may be simply idiotic, but for me it's a bit confusing:

```
In [697]: l=[]

In [698]: bool(l)
Out[698]: False

In [699]: l == True
Out[699]: False

In [700]: l == False
Out[700]: False 

In [701]: False == False
Out[701]: True
```

Why does `l==False` return `False` while `False == False` returns `True`?

Comment: Python comparisons are strongly-typed: [Objects of different types... never compare equal](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html). That's why `l==False` fails.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You are checking it against the literal value of the boolean `False`. The same as `'A' == False` will not be true.

If you cast it, you'll see the difference:

```
>>> l = []
>>> l is True
False
>>> l is False
False
>>> l == True
False
>>> l == False
False
>>> bool(l) == False
True
```

The reason `False == False` is true is because you are comparing the same objects. It is the same as `2 == 2` or `'A' == 'A'`.

The difficulty comes when you see things like `if l:` and this check never passes. That is because you are checking against the *truth value* of the item. By convention, all these items will fail a boolean check - that is, their boolean value will be `False`:

- `None`
- `False` (obviously)
- Any empty sequence: `''`, `[]`, `()`
- Any "zero" value: `0`, `0.0`, etc.
- Any empty collection: `{}` (an empty dict)
- Anything whose `len()` returns a `0`

These are called "falsey" values. ***Everything else is "true"***. Which can lead to some strange things like:

```
>>> def foo():
...   pass
...
>>> bool(foo)
True
```

It is also good to note here that *methods that don't return an explicit value, always have `None` as their return type*, which leads to this:

```
>>> def bar():
...   x = 1+1
...
>>> bool(bar)
True
>>> bool(bar())
False
```

Comment: thanks. as you maybe noticed, it started as discussion in the comments about if you could replace "if len(l):" just with "if l:" this clears things up.

Comment: An empty collection is the same as having a `len()` of 0. Applies to lists, tuples, sets, and dictionaries.

Comment: You are right, but the reason it is mentioned explicitly in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html) is to clarify that any object that implements `__len__()` and returns `0` will be considered "Falsey".

Answer (score 8):

An empty list is not the same as `False`, but `False` equals `False` because it's the same object. `bool(l)` returns `False` because an empty list is "falsy".

In short, `==` is not `bool() == bool()`.

For example, `[1, 2] == [1, 2, 3]` is `False`, even if the two are "truly".

Answer (score 3):

It is because the empty list is not `False`, it is just "falsy" when converted to a `bool`, or when evaluated by the an `if` or `while` condition (which both evaluate the `bool` conversion of their condition). See the [documentation on Truth Value Testing](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) for more detail.