# Why "[ ] and {}" expression return [ ] in python?(Why are [] and {} false?)

Tags: python, boolean-expression

I am wondering about why  [] and {} return [] in python?

```
>>> [] and {}
[]
```

Edit: Why are [] and {} false?I understand and or expressions , but i cannot understand [] and {} expressions are false?

Comment: Because they both are `False` then first is returned.

Comment: Why [] and {} false?I understand and or expressions , but i cannot understand [] and {} expressions are false?

Comment: @mw-b, ...because they're empty. See ie. [empty list boolean value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997305/empty-list-boolean-value), or [How do I check if a list is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/how-do-i-check-if-a-list-is-empty).

Answer (score 3):

In the short circuit evaluation containing only operator `and` (could be multiple) and multiple operators, the expression returns the first *falsy* value, in this case which is `[]` -- an empty list.

In the case where all the values are *truthy*, it returns the last value.

```
# [] and {} both are falsey
In [77]: [] and {}
Out[77]: []

# 3 is truthy, {} is falsey
In [78]: 3 and {}
Out[78]: {}

# all except {} are truthy
In [79]: 3 and 9 and {}
Out[79]: {}

# you get it...
In [80]: 3 and 9 and {} and 10
Out[80]: {}
```

Comment: In addition to this, the reason that the _first_ falsy value is returned rather than some other one like the last or middle is that of an optimization technique called [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: or the second value if neither are falsey

Comment: @avigil Just added.